# NodeJS / Express : Add default subscription period to user account

Tags: node.js, express, payment, subscription, account

I'm building an application with express framework and I want to set a default subscription period to user when get registered ( 6 months by default for example ), after that period, user must pay a specific amount to get access to the app, can some one explain or help by technicals ideas ?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');    
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  passwordHash: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  acceptTerms: Boolean,

  subscriptionPeriod:{
    type: Number,
    default: 6
  },
  payed:{
    type:Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  verificationToken: String,
  verified: Date,
  resetToken: {
    token: String,
    expires: Date
  },

  passwordReset: Date,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated: Date
});

schema.virtual('isVerified').get(function() {
  return !!(this.verified || this.passwordReset);
});    
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use scheduler in node js which will invoke like whatever duration you want to set. There is a package `node-cron` [node-cron package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).
   With this you can scheduler every day and write logic to check which user plan has expired, based on that you can trigger email or disable the account.

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
var job = cron.schedule('0 0 0 * * *', function() {
 //will run every day at 12:00 AM
  //set logic here to check if expiry date is 6 month
})
```

2. AWS lambda can also be used if working with aws. For more information visit this link
   [Scheduling with aws lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)